# How to mock a React Hook setter in Jest (Function bound dispatchAction)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am passing a setter as a prop:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState();

return <MyComponent
   // ...
   isSelected={setSelected}
/>
```

When I come to test, I want to check that this prop has been passed correctly along with my other props:

```
it("should call MyComponent with the correct props", () => {
  renderComponent(args);
  
  expect(MyComponent).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    // ...
    setSelected: jest.fn(),
  });
});
```

Why doesn't my mock of `setSelected` qualify in my test as a match?

> Expected: "setSelected": [Function mockConstructor]

> Received: "setSelected": [Function bound dispatchAction]

What do I need to mock `setSelected` to in my test to get this to work?